# Changing the legend names

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(dataset, aes( x = Norm, fill = Condition, y=log2(measure))) + geom_boxplot() +
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("brown1","darkolivegreen4","burlywood3")) + theme_classic() + 
        labs(title="Comparison",x="Norm", y = "counts") +
        scale_fill_continuous(labels = paste("condition1", "condition2", "condition3"))
```

I am trying to change the labels of the legend. Currently, it shows the labels that are present in my dataset. However, I want to change it to "condition1", "condition2", "condition3". Above is the code I am trying. It gives me following error.

```
Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale. Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale In addition: Warning message: Removed 18 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

Could someone help me here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about bioinformatics. Also this problem is answered in Stack Overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have any continuous fill scales, since you're filling according to `Condition`, which is a factor. This is leading to the `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` error. You just need to combine your previous `scale_fill_manual(values=...)` command with the `labels=` part of your incorrect `scale_fill_continuous()` command:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes( x = Norm, fill = Condition, y=log2(measure))) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("brown1","darkolivegreen4","burlywood3"),
                      labels = paste("condition1", "condition2", "condition3")) +
    theme_classic() + 
    labs(title="Comparison",x="Norm", y = "counts")
```

Something along those lines should work.